# How to highlight all instances of a net in Eagle? (multi-sheet schematic)

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

I'm adding some components to an existing design in Eagle.  It's currently a 4 sheet schematic.  I want be 100% sure that the net I've labelled on one sheet is connected to the desired net on another sheet.  For example, that the net named MOTOR_C_D2 on a FET on one sheet is in fact connected to a GPIO line labelled MOTOR_C_D2 on my AVR CPU (they are on separate sheets).

I did a Tools->Search for MOTOR_C_D2 and it only highlighted the pin on my CPU.  It did not highlight the pin I have on the FET also labelled the same.  I would expect that a search would highlight ALL components on all sheets of a schematic that met the search string, but perhaps Eagle doesn't work that way?

Thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `show` command will highlight a net in all views.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick.  Don't know why the search command doesn't do this?